# Theoretical question about memory usage

Tags: ram, console

I'm wondering about following issue:

Taken some `abc` console(no matter if `bash`,`zsh` or something) in some *nix system.
If I start some process `stuff` which uses 2MB of memory and then launch second instance of process `stuff`, how much memory will be used in total?

Is it true that 4MB of memory now will be used?

Comment: @muru But these posts only mention differences between used memory in RAM and swapped out to the hdd. I think there has to be more. Let me finish my answer...

Comment: @ByteCommander Not necessarily. The posts also discuss RSS vs SHR, I think. If not, I might have copied the wrong links.

Comment: @ByteCommander Yep, looks like I copied the wrong links. http://serverfault.com/questions/48582/how-is-memory-usage-reported-in-linux discusses RSS and SHR.

Answer (score 2):

If the processes are both launched independently, we should assume that each process would run as if no other "twin" process is started (as long as they don't need to control the same resources, e.g. files). I think this is the case for most simple programs without GUI or any need to care about multiple instances.

However, the system can avoid this and share constant static data between all process instances. This data can consist of the binary code, constants, shared libraries, etc...

Additionally, when you only care about physical RAM usage, you also have to think about the swap. Linux will push rarely used data to the swap partition/file on the hard disk to free some faster RAM as cache.

**So to conclude:** *It is hard to tell how much memory will be used by many equal processes, because the kernel optimizes the usage by sharing constant data between the different instances, but you can be almost sure that it will be less than n times the usage of one single process.*